# Enable and Disable buttons based on textbox values

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have 24 buttons in which is written time, 24hours.

First `button1.Text="01:00"`, `button2.Text="02:00"`, `button3.Text="03:00"` and so on.....till `button24.Text="00:00"`

And I have two textboxes (`workStart.Text` and `workFinishes.Text`), where the user types different times, some days they work 10 hours and other days less hours.

For example `workStart.Text="08:00"` and `workFinishes.Text="18:00"`. So all the buttons from 08:00 till 18:00 range must be enabled  and the rest must be disabled in this case (according textbox values).

I would really appreciate it if someone will help to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`String.Compare()` will work for the comparison. To get all buttons you can use `var buttons = buttonsParent.Controls.OfType<Button>().ToList()` of the buttons parent or you can put them in an array yourself like `var buttons = new Button[] { button1, button2, ... }`

Then:

```
foreach(var btn in buttons)
   btn.Enabled = string.Compare(btn.Text, workStart.Text) >= 0 &&
                 string.Compare(btn.Text, workFinishes.Text) <= 0;
```

Comment: Glad I could help. It should be like: `var currentTime = DateTime.Now;currentTime = currentTime.AddHours(1);` or even simple: `var currentTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);`

Comment: I appreciate your help, it works perfectly as I wish. I have difficulties to solve one more thing with the above question, I need to take the current time 
`var currentTime = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1); `
compare it with the enabled buttons and if the currentTime(+1hour) is greater than the time in button it should disable this button because its already passed.

Comment: as you comparisons are in string, you should do something like: `if(string.Compare( DateTime.Now.AddHours(1).ToString("HH:mm"), btn.Text) >=0) ....`

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the Texts into TimeSpans and then set the `Enabled` property of the buttons based on whether their time is within the range:

```
var workStartTime = TimeSpan.Parse(workStart.Text);
var workEndTime = TimeSpan.Parse(workEnd.Text);
foreach (var button in allButtons)
{
    var buttonTime = TimeSpan.Parse(button.Text);
    button.Enabled = buttonTime >= workStartTime && buttonTime <= workEndTime;
}
```